# Automatic weights application issue

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, parent

When I parent my mesh and armature with automatic weights, the weights don't work properly. I have tried recalculating normals, but it did not work.

This is my mesh and armature:
[image: This is my mesh and armature.]

This is the way the automatic weights are getting assigned:
[image: This is the way the automatic weights are getting assigned.]

This problem is occurring for all bones. I also tried deleting the armature and used a new armature, but the same problem occurred.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-vN7FM3090J54ogq-O5aAbXj85c45Vz4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I just found out that I was making all the changes in one of the shapekeys and not in basis. When I tried to parent it again in basis it worked. But thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the result you are showing there.

Try this:

In object mode: select your cat

[image]

now Shift-select your armature:

[image]

press CTRL-P -> with automatic weights

if you then move your bones, it looks good (to me):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your mesh have some overlapping vertices that shouldn't be there, it confuses the automatic weighting, leading to the weights being erratic and inconsistent (which also explains why we don't get the same result on each weight generation).

To fix that: select your mesh, go into Edit Mode, hit <kbd>M</kbd> → Merge by distance

Set the distance to `0.0051 m` (replace the last zero by five).

After that, go back into object mode. Select your mesh object, them <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select your armature and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> → Armature Deform with automatic weights.

This should help. Though, the ultimate fix would be to have a correct topology for your model. But that isn't something that can be easily described in an answer, so I highly suggest you to get inform on the subject and find examples of cat mesh topology online to follow.

Comment: I had tried that but it did not work